# how to cache image with a new one which have the same url?

Tags: android, caching, android-glide, image-caching

i have listview to load images for alot of users and this listview item has an imageview for profile picture of user, the problem here if the user changed his the new image will not be shown as last profile picture is cached  and the old one will be displayed because the new and old image have the same url:
**URL EX:**
"https://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/users/" + friend_id + "/photos/profile.jpg"

i used [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) but i have the same problem

Comment: Use something like file hashing and fetch new one if hash fails!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is because of the cache of images, Glide checks if image is available in cache, if it does glide loads it else it would load the new image.

To solve this issue you need to change its cache strategy like this

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load((Integer) mDataset.get(position))
            .fitCenter()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) // this will prevent image to be cached and each time glide will load it from server
            .into(imageView);
```